# Jquery window resize function for this script css Menu

Tags: jquery, css

I'm very new in jQuery but I made some mix in a code and get a very nice menu. It is working good but when I resize the window the line that is below the active link, lose it X axis position. Here is a code pen so you can check it out.

I know I have to put something like this but I don't know how to implement it. Can anyone help me with this?

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
});
```

http://codepen.io/asdf/pen/EPMEZZ

Comment: You have to show us the HTML that you want to change on the resize, and you need to explain what the resize should do.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The HTML was in the codepen link. Anyway The problem is solved. Regards

Comment: A good question contains the relevant code, PLUS a CodePen.  This question will be useless when that link to the codepen breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the left position of the active class you can move the menu-line to that position

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
defaultPosition = $(".active").offset().left;
$("#menu-line").css("left", defaultPosition+"px");
};
```

However that creates new problems because the hover out function has a different position recorded hence the reason when you hover out of a menu option after a window resize the position is not correct

removing the code in the hover out and adding the below fixes the issue

```
defaultPosition = $(".active").offset().left;
$("#menu-line").css("left", defaultPosition+"px");
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyorwE?editors=0110)

Comment: Tasos, thank you for your reply but the menu, after resizing the window does not stay in the proper link, it goes to the left. Can you help me with this